# Tasks "block" each other

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I've discovered a weird behavior in Grunt where it seems that two tasks block each other (or something like that). The tasks are: shell (https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) and sass (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass).

My (reduced) Gruntfile;

```
"use strict";

var path        = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        shell: {
            options: {
                stdout: true,
                stderr: true
            },
            bower: {
                command: path.resolve(process.cwd() + '/node_modules/.bin/bower --allow-root install')
            }
        },

        /* ... other tasks */

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    trace: true
                },

                files: {
                    'dist/additional.css': 'assets/stylesheets/additional.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'shell',
        'sass',
    ]);

}
```

When I start `grunt` my shell task is finished but grunt "stops" at the shell task:

```
Running "shell:bower" (shell) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

### ctrl + c ###

Execution Time (2015-04-06 10:56:14 UTC)
loading tasks         8.9s  █ 1%
shell:bower          18.6s  ██ 2%
sass:dist        13m 25.2s  ██████████████████████████████████████████████ 97%
Total 13m 52.7s
```

When I start these tasks seperately (with `grunt shell` respectively `grunt sass`) everything works fine.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your dependencies listed on your package.json?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/nehalist/bc0eb3fb5139c495fb46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch `grunt-shell` for it's fork [`grunt-shell-spawn`](https://github.com/cri5ti/grunt-shell-spawn) and try running the task synchronously.

```
shell: {
  options: {
    stdout: true,
    stderr: true,
    async: false
  },
  bower: {
    command: path.resolve(process.cwd() + '/node_modules/.bin/bower --allow-root install')
  }
}
```

Comment: Just by switching to grunt-shell-spawn instead of grunt-shell my problem got solved :) Thanks a lot!